# How to solve 'Error 1 in extracting from .zip' (R)

Tags: r, unzip

As a part of Google DA certificate assignment I was trying to find an elegant solution on how to download unzip and merge multiple .csv files using R, but I keep facing same issue over an over again:

**error 1 in extracting from zip file**

Data:
Source: [Divvy](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

the code I run is:

```
## declare variable file names corresponding to calendar months
months <- c(202011:202012,202101:202110)

## declare directory for storing source files
storage <- "C:\\Users\\...\\start"

## vectors of all urls to download from and destination files
urls <- 
  paste0("https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/",months, "-divvy-tripdata.zip")
  
## idea was to download archives into temporary files, unzip contents to 'storage' directory and remove tempdir.

temp <- tempdir()
tempfile <- paste0(temp,"\\",months,".zip")

##Downloading 12 months archives
for(i in seq(urls)){
  download.file(urls[i],tempfile[i], mode="wb")
}

file_names <- list.files(temp, pattern = ".zip")

for (i in seq(file_names)){
  unzip(file_names,exdir=storage,overwrite = FALSE)}
```

**Warning in unzip("file_names", exdir = storage, overwrite = FALSE) :
error 1 in extracting from zip file**

Everything works until unzip step. All archives are downloaded, can be opened, files are not corrupt, properties shows extension as .zip

I've tried my code on multiple machines, within different directories, tried downloading archives manually, tried unzipping each individual and all at once using loops and `ldply` still same result.

I've spent 3 days trying to solve it and appreciate any help :)

Comment: Forget `file_names`, those are meaningless. What you want is to unzip the temp files written, just replace the `seq` by `seq(tempfile)` and `unzip(tempfile[i], etc)`.

Comment: Many thanks @RuiBarradas! 
Few clarification questions if I could:
So the issue was really due to no paths in `file_names` but names only? which means I shouldn't have created `file_names` but used my tempfile instead.  But then I wonder why my code didn't work despite setting work directory to `tmpdir`, which in my understanding would say unzip files with `file_names` from `tmpdir`?

Comment: You did not set the working directory to `tmpdir`, you created a variable with that name, that's all. And yes, the issue was due to file names with no path, `unzip` was trying to read them from the wd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the same `months`, and `urls` variables, the following seems simpler. Note the different way of putting together the temp file names, with `file.path`.

```
tmpdir <- tempdir()
tmpfile <- file.path(tmpdir, months)
tmpfile <- paste0(tmpfile, ".zip")

##Downloading 12 months archives
for(i in seq(urls)){
  download.file(urls[i], tmpfile[i], mode="wb")
  unzip(tmpfile[i], exdir = storage, overwrite = FALSE)
}
unlink(tmfile)
unlink(tmpdir)

list.files(storage, pattern = "\\.csv")
# [1] "202011-divvy-tripdata.csv" "202012-divvy-tripdata.csv"
# [3] "202101-divvy-tripdata.csv" "202102-divvy-tripdata.csv"
# [5] "202103-divvy-tripdata.csv" "202104-divvy-tripdata.csv"
# [7] "202105-divvy-tripdata.csv" "202106-divvy-tripdata.csv"
# [9] "202107-divvy-tripdata.csv" "202108-divvy-tripdata.csv"
#[11] "202109-divvy-tripdata.csv" "202110-divvy-tripdata.csv"
```